# Angular 2 testing - Renderer is undefined

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine, renderer

Component definition:

```js
export class NoteComponent  {
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef,
        renderer: Renderer,
        _alertService: AlertService) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {

        //Hiding the toolbar when editable by default.
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement.children[0].children[2].children[0], 'display', 'none');
    }
}
```

Test

```js
describe('NoteComponent (external template)', () => {
    let comp: NoteComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<NoteComponent>;
    let de: DebugElement;
    let el: HTMLElement;

    let rendererMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('rendererMock', ['selectRootElement',
        'createElement',
        'createViewRoot',
        'createText',
        'setElementProperty',
        'setElementAttribute',
        'setText',
        'setBindingDebugInfo',
        'createTemplateAnchor',
        'projectNodes',
        'attachViewAfter',
        'detachView',
        'destroyView',
        'listen',
        'listenGlobal',
        'setElementClass',
        'setElementStyle',
        'invokeElementMethod',
        'animate']);

    let rootRendererMock = {
        renderComponent: () => {
            return rendererMock;
        }
    };

    beforeEach(async () => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                NoteComponent,
                SafePipe], // declare the test component
            providers: [AlertService,
                { provide: Renderer, useValue: rootRendererMock }]
        })
            .overrideComponent(NoteComponent, {
                set: {
                    providers: [
                        { provide: Renderer, useValue: rootRendererMock }
                    ]
                }
            });

        TestBed.compileComponents();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NoteComponent);
        comp = fixture.componentInstance;
     });
     
     it('note: note not on favorite page, not faved', async () => {
        comp.pinnedOnFavWall = false;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.favorite'));
        expect(de).toBeDefined();
    });
```

The test passes since it is async, but I get this error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
>    at DomRenderer.webpackJsonp.../../../platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.js.DomRenderer.setElementStyle (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/dom_renderer.js:395:1)
>       at DebugDomRenderer.webpackJsonp.../../../core/src/debug/debug_renderer.js.DebugDomRenderer.setElementStyle (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/@angular/core/src/debug/debug_renderer.js:223:1)
>       at NoteComponent.ngAfterViewInit (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/Scripts/app/components/controls/Note/note.component.ts:67:23)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_NoteComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/DynamicTestModule/NoteComponent/host.ngfactory.js:32:72)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.webpackJsonp.../../../core/src/linker/view.js.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:425:1)
>       at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.webpackJsonp.../../../core/src/linker/view.js.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:620:1)
>       at ViewRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/src/linker/view_ref.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/@angular/core/src/linker/view_ref.js:181:1)
>       at ComponentFixture._tick (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:191:1)
>       at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:205:46
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:365:26)
>       at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:1)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:364:32)
>       at Object.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/C:/Shilpa/Work/Freelancing/ArugamBay/Code/ArugambaySite2/src/Arugambay.Web/~/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:271:1)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:364:32)
>       at Zone.run (http://localhost:9876/base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:43)

How do I get rid of this error?
Even without the mock, I get the same error.

PS: Component code edited for brevity. So, the line numbers in the stack may not match.

Comment: Which angular version are you using?

Comment: private renderer: Renderer,

Comment: @yurzui, Angular 2.4.4

Comment: @Milad, changing the access specifier of renderer didn't help.